# Find infinitely many integral solutions $(x^2+x+1)(y^2+y+1)=z^2 +z+1 $

Tags: number-theory

Find infinitely many integral solutions $(x^2+x+1)(y^2+y+1)=z^2 +z+1 $

My assumption: $(x=y=z=0), (x=z, y=0) (x=0, y=z)$. Is there any other way to find. If so, please help me to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same with $-1$ in place of $0$

Comment: $(x,y,z)=(1,2,4)$

Comment: List out the values for $x=1$ to $20$, and find trios that work

Comment: duplicate of https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h379368p2097807

Answer (score 1):

Set $y=-x$. Then 
\begin{align}
(x^2+x+1)(y^2+y+1)&= (x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)\\
&=((x^2+1)+x)((x^2+1)-x)\\
&= (x^2+1)^2-x^2.
\end{align}

The latter expression is exactly $x^4+x^2+1$, so setting $y=-x$ and $z=x^2$ gives you infinitely many integral solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an infinite set of cases where all of $x,y,z$ are positive.

If $w=(1+\sqrt{-3})/2$ then $$(a+b w)(a+b\overline w)=a^2+ab+b^2.$$

Now $(1+xw)(1+y\overline w)=1+xy+y + (x-y)w$

So if $x-y=1$ we get a solution.

So:

$$(1+x+x^2)(1+(x-1)+(x-1)^2)=1+(x^2)+(x^2)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

A "less trivial" infinite collection of solutions comes from the following observation:

Let $\omega=\frac{1+ i\sqrt 3}2$. Then $\omega^2=\omega-1$ and
$$\left|x+\omega\right|^2=\left|x+\overline \omega\right|^2=(x+\omega)(x+\overline\omega)=x^2+x+1.$$
Also note that
$$ (\omega+x)(\omega-x)=\omega^2-x^2=\omega-x^2-1$$
is again of this form, so  $x\in\Bbb Z$, $y=-x$, $z=-x^2-1$ gives another infinite set of solutions.
(Of course, you could also just verify this directly without the complex number motivation)